# How to get key and values in php

Tags: php, arrays

***I KNOW IMDB WONT ALLOW THIS. THIS IS JUST A TEST*** 
i'm so stuck on this very basic array. i've tried every thing but i cant get this printed . i'm using this php library https://github.com/FabianBeiner/PHP-IMDB-Grabber
for grabbing some information from imdb website.

The output is multidimensional array but i can't print it.
i'm using this method `getCastImages($iLimit = 0, $bMore = true, $sSize = 'small', $bDownload = false)`. 
the out put is like this:

```
Array
(
    [Ryan Reynolds] => https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTI3ODk1MTMyNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDEyNTE2Mg@@._V1_SX26_CR0,0,26,35_.jpg
    [Karan Soni] => https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg0NjQ1MTU1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTAyMzc1MDE@._V1_SX26_CR0,0,26,35_.jpg
)
```

and this:

```
Array
(
    [getAka] => Array
        (
            [name] => Aka
            [value] => X-Men Origins: Deadpool (United States) | X-Men: Deadpool (United States) | Дедпул (Ukraine) | Дэдпул (Russia) | Dedpul (Serbia)
        )

    [getAkas] => Array
        (
            [name] => Akas
            [value] => Deadpool / Argentina / Deadpool / Chile / Deadpool / Czech Republic / Deadpool / Germany / Deadpool / Denmark / Deadpool / Spain / Deadpool / Finland / Deadpool / France / Deadpool / Greece / Deadpool / Croatia / Deadpool / Italy / Дедпул / Republic of Macedonia / Deadpool / Mexico / Deadpool / Norway / Deadpool / Portugal / Deadpool / Romania / Dedpul / Serbia / Дэдпул / Russia / Deadpool / Sweden / Дедпул / Ukraine
        )
)
```

**update:** 
 i don't know why but the `foreach` should be like this!

```
  $castImages = $IMDB->getCastImages(5, false, 'mid');
    foreach (explode(' / ', $IMDB->getCast(5, false)) as $name) {
        echo '<img src="' . $castImages[$name] . '" alt="' . $name . '">' . $name . '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: what do you want the printed version to look like?

Comment: is imply want to print casts name and show their picture with <img> in html. not a huge thing!

Comment: `foreach($arr as $key => $value) { var_dump($key); var_dump($value); }`?

Comment: Have you read `IMDb doesn’t allow this method of data fetching.`? You should use an IMDb API if available.

Comment: man I've tried that i'm not that beginner. it's not working!

Comment: "Its not working" is not very descriptive. Describe what SHOULD happen, and the parts that are not. Provide examples of your actual code-that-does-not-work as well.

Comment: Also, did you look at the provided example? https://github.com/FabianBeiner/PHP-IMDB-Grabber/blob/master/examples/imdb.example.php ... line 99 has exactly that.

Comment: yeah you'r right! i think i sat behind my screen alot :) i should get some air. i know imdb isn't allow this . this was just a test. is there any API for that kind of thing?

Answer (score 4):

For your first example you can do:

```
foreach($arr as $name => $img) {
  echo $name;
  echo $img;
}
```

For the second example you will have to use 2 `foreach` loops like so:

```
foreach($aka as $k => $v) {
  foreach($v as $key => $value) {
    echo $k;
    echo $v;
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: no but it this will work :|  `$castImages = $IMDB->getCastImages(5, false, 'small');
    foreach (explode(' / ', $IMDB->getCast(5, false)) as $name) {
        echo '<img src="' . $castImages[$name] . '" alt="' . $name . '">' . $name . '<br>';
    }`

Comment: @AmirMeimari Even though the github provided example has it that way .... in theory there could be a better way to just loop over `$castImages` like uom's example instead of pulling the cats and doing that odd explode way.